I'm attempting to mount a drive located at /dev/sdX to a specific directory using the following command: sudo mount /dev/sdX /mnt/mydrive
What I’ve Tried:
Checked the drive’s file system using sudo fdisk -l.
Verified the directory exists with ls /mnt/mydrive.
Tried mounting with different options, such as specifying the file system type with -t
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sdX /mnt/mydrive
But still problem is not resolved.

does this tutorial help?

What is the "problem" exactly? What is the error message? Have you run the mount command with the -v (or --verbose) option to get additional diagnostic information?
